# Compile error. Fallback function error

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-design, fallback-function, truffle-compile

I use pragma 0.6.2. I am trying copile in truffle code which contain this lines:

fallback() external payable{}

I an getting error:

The payable fallback function is defined here.
fallback() external payable{}
^---------------------------^

Comment: That snippet of code by itself compiles just fine. The error if exists should be the surrounding code.

Comment: Thanks. I have solved problem. I changed fallback() on receive();